# What does DataStax OpsCenter do with my AWS Credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, datastax, opscenter

OpsCenter has a cloud cluster configurator that takes aws credentials and (presumably) spins up a Cassandra cluster for you

Does anyone know all of the things that OpsCenter does with those credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpsCenter developer here, I work on the cloud launching features. It creates a securitygroup if you ask it to, creates a keypair if you ask it to, launches the number of instances you request and deploys DSE/DSC to them.  At the end of the provisioning run, it forgets your credentials.  Basically what you'd guess based on the form fields and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Correct -- OpsCenter provisioning can spin up nodes on AWS for you using your AWS credentials. See the OpsC docs below for details:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.1/opsc/online_help/opscCreatingCluster_t.html